# Java web logic error out of sudden

Tags: java, web-services, weblogic, host

I am developing a java web application. It was running well but today I opened Eclipse and all imported libraries are throwing errors. As if I didn't have those libs.

I didn't modify my project. The only thing different that I've done was to try to generate the JavaDoc. Now I can't even run my server, it gets a `CONNECTION REFUSED` error.. I need some help, if I try to restore Windows will it work?

Comment: have you tried restarting eclipse?

Comment: Exactly what errors are you getting? Have you refreshed the project to be really sure?

Comment: Yes, I've restarted Eclipse and my computer 2 or 3 times.. Tried to clean my project, remove my preject from my web logic server. But when I was going to add it again my project doesn't appears on the add list!!!!

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the error or the stack trace? Without more information on the specific error it is hard to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done another Project, copying the classes from this Project. Add it to my Debug on my server and it`s working. Thank you all for the help